# Converting JSON response to python object

Tags: python, json, http, response

I want to convert HTTP GET response (I am using [requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/#)) to python object. Here's my code:

```
# Full, pure, response
response = requests.get(url)

# Getting request data/content represented in byte array
content = response.content

# Byte array to string
data = content.decode('utf8')


# This line causes "ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f35068be128>"
#data = ast.literal_eval(data)

# I tried this also but data is still string after those 2 lines
data = json.dumps(data)
data = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

Comment: `content = response.json()` ?

Comment: Could you show us how your `response.text` looks like, if it is a valid json object, then only you can perform `dumps` or `loads` on it @DolidodTeethtard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the response as a dictionary using `content = response.json()`, and then pass that `content` to `json.loads` directly (This is assuming your response comes as a json)

```
# Full, pure, response
response = requests.get(url)

# Getting response as dictionary
content = response.json()

#Loading dictionary as json
data = json.loads(content, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, but respone.json() returns dict, and I needed to convert it to string with this line `content = json.dumps(data)`

Comment: You don't have that line `content = json.dumps(data)` in your code in the question. Instead you do `data = json.dumps(data)` and then `data = json.loads(data,`, whereas now you have your `content` as a dictionary, so you only need `json.dumps`